# Hierarchical classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, multiclass-classification

I have a multi-class problem. I want to solve this problem using the LCPN (Local Classifier per Parent Node) method of heirachical classification. Therefore, I have manually divided the original dataset into a hierarchy of 2 levels. Level 1 has, 4 parent classes & each of the parent classes have child classes.

I built a model for level 1 classification (for predicting the parent class). Based on the predictions of level 1, now I want to send the instances that were classified as class 1, to a second classifier that distinguishes between the child labels of class 1. Likewise, I want to repeat this process for the other parent classes as well. I’m mainly doing this to avoid, inconsistency problem associated with LCPN.

This is what I have mainly done so far.

```
X = data_frame.drop([‘region’], axis = 1) # Features
y = data_frame[‘region’] # Labels

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

sm = SMOTE()
X_resampled, y_resampled = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X_resampled, y_resampled)
print(classification_report_imbalanced(y_test, predictions))
```

I’m bit struggling finding a way how to proceed further with the second level of classification, based on the predictions of level 1. Can anyone suggest me a good way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

We just released a new library compatible with scikit-learn to create local hierarchical classifiers. You can easily create a local classifier per parent node with `lcppn = LocalClassifierPerParent(local_classifier=RandomForestClassifier())`, then fit your model with `lcppn.fit()` and predict with `lcppn.predict()`. The library does all the heavy lifting for you. :)

It can be easily installed with `pip install hiclass` or `conda install hiclass`. Documentation and more examples can be found at https://gitlab.com/dacs-hpi/hiclass.

I hope this will be useful for you and future readers.

Comment: Hello @Fabio, regarding the HiClass library, I would like to inquire if it is possible to use TensorFlow and Keras models as input for the local_classifier component?

Comment: Hi @tasrif
Yes, it is possible, but your model has to follow the scikit-learn API. Here it shows how to build sklearn compatible estimators: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html